# How test whether Catalog window of ArcMap is open (and docked)?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#

From ArcMap 10 when the Catalog window is open, how can I test whether  ArcCatalog isOpen (and docked) using ArcObjects and C#.